# Adding boost adaptation to google cloud speech in java

Tags: java, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, google-speech-api, google-cloud-speech

I'm using google's cloud speech api  for speech to text conversion via microphone can anyone tell me how can i add a boost adaptation to my java code so the i can assign proper boost values to certain phrases.
i need to do this in java.
i've read an google document in which shows how you can add the values in json request :
here's that link : " https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/speech-adaptation" (at the bottom)

i need to do the same in java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing a bit of research and reading the official documentation i finally found the solution to this on cloud speech document the answer mentioned by absin is also correct here's where i found the solution.

: https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/context-strength

Thanks for the help :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `setBoost` in `SpeechContext` builder and `addSpeechContexts` of the `RecognitionConfig` builder.

```
List<String> phrases = new ArrayList<String>();
phrases.add("Sheryar");
SpeechContext item = SpeechContext.newBuilder().addAllPhrases(phrases).setBoost(20f).build();
RecognitionConfig recognitionConfig = RecognitionConfig.newBuilder().setEncoding(RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.LINEAR16).setLanguageCode("en-IN").addSpeechContexts(item).setSampleRateHertz(48000).setEnableWordTimeOffsets(true);
```

You need to do the following imports:

```
import com.google.cloud.speech.v1p1beta1.RecognitionAudio;
import com.google.cloud.speech.v1p1beta1.RecognitionConfig;
import com.google.cloud.speech.v1p1beta1.RecognizeRequest;
import com.google.cloud.speech.v1p1beta1.RecognizeResponse;
import com.google.cloud.speech.v1p1beta1.SpeechClient;
import com.google.cloud.speech.v1p1beta1.SpeechContext;
import com.google.cloud.speech.v1p1beta1.SpeechRecognitionAlternative;
import com.google.cloud.speech.v1p1beta1.SpeechRecognitionResult;
```

And you need to add the following dependency to your pom:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.cloud/google-cloud-speech -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-cloud-speech</artifactId>
    <version>1.22.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: i know how to add a speech context but i want to know that how to add different boost adaptation level to two words as shown in the link that i've mentioned

Comment: I modified my answer to reflect the same.

Comment: can you check for this :            
                                      https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59845869/com-google-api-gax-rpc-unavailableexception-io-grpc-statusruntimeexception-una  cloud speech work on my other machine but when i'm trying to do this on my other laptop it gives me the error as mentioned.